# Как задать размер виртуальной памяти в windows 7?

Tags: windows, память

Я с 7-кой сойду с ума!
Выставляю ПРИНУДИТЕЛЬНО (!!!) размер своп-файла на исходный 2048 мб, макс 4096 мб!
Это "Любимая" мной windows, сама потом меняет размер (в диапазоне) на 800 мб - до 1200 мб!
Что это? Как это? И почему это?
Она имеет исскусственный разум?
Почему она переназначает мои назначения ей?
Как остановить произвол Windows?
Как подчинить строптивую?

Comment: и даже кнопочку "задать" не забыли жмякнуть?

Comment: Спрошу на всякий случай... перегружался после принудительного назначения?

Comment: Продолжайте наблюдения.

Comment: Да конечно жмакнул! Как же не жмакнуть.Я ж с 98-го с форточками от Билла дружу.

Answer (score 1):

надеюсь и оперативы подходящее количество?

Comment: При чём тут ОЗУ?

Comment: Матчасть учите: виртуалка должна выделяться в объеме равной 2хОЗУ. Т.е. если ОЗУ 1ГБ, то виртуалка должна быть 2 (2048 МБ).   Плюс последние нововведения от мелкомягких - учитывая, что сейчас у всех объемы ОЗУ не слабые, то 7 и 8 -ка больше исполняемого кода подгружают в ОЗУ, для ускорения работы (ибо своп медленный). Поэтому, в совокупности, ОС сама решает сколько ей свопа требуется. Если же неймется, попробуйте сделать дополнительный своп на другом физическом ЖД, или использовать оба свопа.